# Debating: Average of the Average vs Average

Tags: statistics, data-science, cluster-analysis, average

I know this is an old question. You will probably conclude that Average of the Average is always wrong. Consider the following example:
You want to know the purchasing behaviour for a supermarket by understanding the share% of the baskeket. For each order, you can have a share% across product categories. The dataset can be like this:
order_id, grocery%, tabacco%, cloth%, etc. The share% is based on the order amount. Each row is a unique order_id.

If you are summing up all grocery amount and divided by total order amount, you can indeed get the average grocery share. If given more contexts, let's say, the VIP in this supermarket accounts for 10% and each order they can spend 1 million (just assumption). So it is quite possible that the result tends to be close to the VIP result.

If I am more interested in the average player behaviour, it seems to use the average of the average metric, which is this one: (grocery% + grocery% + ...)/order number.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This Question is more appropriate in [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) as it is not relevant to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

So let me try to answer your question with an example.

Let us say, there were only three purchases made in the supermarket.

> Purchase 1

```
Grocery Amount = 30$ (60%)
Cloth Amount = 20$   (40%)
```

> Purchase 2

```
Grocery Amount = 10$ (50%)
Cloth Amount = 10$   (50%)
```

> Purchase 3

```
Grocery Amount = 5$ (25%)
Cloth Amount = 15$  (75%)
```

Now let us calculate our metrics:

### Approach "Average of Average"

Final Answer = (25% + 50% + 60%)/3 = 45%

### Approach "Average"

Final Answer = (5$ + 10$ + 30$)*100/140$ = 32.14%

## Conclusion

Given the example above, obviously, the "average" approach leads to a more accurate result. But given your use case, you can use any of these.

Hope this helps!